# Using importsScripts within Blob in a karma environment

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, web-worker

I am working on a small project of mine using karma, and jasmine. My targeted browser is chrome 32.

I am trying to import scripts within a web worker whom I have instanciated through a blob  as follows :

```
describeAsyncAppliPersephone("When the application project to DOM", function()
{
    it("it should call the function of DomProjection in the project associated with its event", function()
    {
        var eventSentBack = {
            eventType: 'testReceived',
            headers: { id: 14, version: 4 },
            payLoad: { textChanged: 'newText' }
        };
        var isRendered = false;
        var fnProjection = function(event, payload)
        {
            isRendered = true;
        }

        var bootstrap = [
            { eventType: 'testReceived', projection: fnProjection },
            { eventType: 'test2Received', projection: function() { } }
        ];

        runs(function()
        {
            var factory = new WorkerFactory();

        var worker = factory.CreateByScripts('importScripts("/base/SiteWeb/project/js/app/application.js"); var app = new application(self); app.projectOnDOM(' + JSON.stringify(eventSentBack) + '); ');

            console.log(worker.WorkerLocation);

            var applicationQueue = new queueAsync(worker);
            var projectQueue = new queueSync(worker);
            var p = new project(applicationQueue, persephoneQueue, bootstrap);

            applicationQueue.publish(eventSentBack);
        });

        waitsFor(function() { return isRendered }, "Projection called", 500);

        runs(function()
        {
            expect(isRendered).toBe(true);
        });


    });
});
```

workerFactory is as follows :

```
this.CreateByScripts = function(scripts, fDefListener, fOnError)
    {
        var arrayScripts = scripts;

        if (!arrayScripts)
            throw "unable to load worker for undefined scripts";

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arrayScripts) !== '[object Array]')
            arrayScripts = [arrayScripts];

        var blob = new Blob(arrayScripts, { type: "text/javascript" });

        var w = createWorker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

        return new QueryableWorker(w, fDefListener, fOnError);
    }
```

where createWorker is :

```
createWorker = function(sUrl)
        {
            return new Worker(sUrl);
        }
```

But the importScripts throws me the following error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'importScripts': the URL
>   '/base/SiteWeb/project/js/app/application.js' is invalid.

I have tried with the path within the browser :

```
http://mylocalhost:9876/base/SiteWeb/project/js/app/application.js
```

and it does work well.

What is the path I should use to make importScripts working successfully ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't use relative path in worker created with Blob.

Had this problem today. Solution is explained in ["The Basics of Web Workers"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/), but a little hidden in length of the article:

> The reason being: the worker (now created from a blob URL) will be resolved with a blob: prefix, while your app will be running from a different (presumably http://) scheme. Hence, the failure will be due to cross origin restrictions.

If you are determined to avoid hardcoding domain name in your workers the article has also a solution for this. Import your scripts on receiving a message with URL as one of its parameters:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    importScripts(e.data.url + 'yourscript.js');
};
```

and start your worker with sending that url

```
worker.postMessage({url: document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.host});
```

The code above is simplified for clarity.

Comment: brilliant!!! I did find a solution but it was a bit more hacky than yours.... have a nice day!!!

Comment: I believe it should be `document.location.protocol` and `document.location.host`, respectively.